# Infix expression calculator racket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

So i got this code:

```
#lang pl

  #| BNF for the AE language:
     <AE> ::= <num>
            | { + <AE> <AE> }
            | { - <AE> <AE> }
            | { * <AE> <AE> }
            | { / <AE> <AE> }
  |#

  ;; AE abstract syntax trees
  (define-type AE
    [Num Number]
    [Add AE AE]
    [Sub AE AE]
    [Mul AE AE]
    [Div AE AE])

  (: parse-sexpr : Sexpr -> AE)
  ;; to convert s-expressions into AEs
  (define (parse-sexpr sexpr)
    (match sexpr
      [(number: n) (Num n)]
      [(list '+ lhs rhs)
       (Add (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
      [(list '- lhs rhs)
       (Sub (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
      [(list '* lhs rhs)
       (Mul (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
      [(list '/ lhs rhs)
       (Div (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
      [else
      (error 'parse-sexpr "bad syntax in ~s" sexpr)]))

  (: parse : String -> AE)
  ;; parses a string containing an AE expression to an AE AST
  (define (parse str)
    (parse-sexpr (string->sexpr str)))

  (: eval : AE -> Number)
  ;; consumes an AE and computes the corresponding number
  (define (eval expr)
    (cases expr
      [(Num n)   n]
      [(Add l r) (+ (eval l) (eval r))]
      [(Sub l r) (- (eval l) (eval r))]
      [(Mul l r) (* (eval l) (eval r))]
      [(Div l r) (/ (eval l) (eval r))]))

  (: run : String -> Number)
  ;; evaluate an AE program contained in a string
  (define (run str)
    (eval (parse str)))
```

you can test and run is with `run (+ 3 5)` and the you will get 8.

my mission is to change the code so i can do `run (3 + 5)`

so i change the parse-sexpr function who build the tree it self to:

```
  (: parse-sexpr : Sexpr -> AE)
  ;; to convert s-expressions into AEs
  (define (parse-sexpr sexpr)
    (match sexpr
      [(number: n) (Num n)]
      [(list lhs '+ rhs)
       (Add (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
      [(list lhs '- rhs)
       (Sub (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
      [(list lhs '* rhs)
       (Mul (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
      [(list lhs '/ rhs)
       (Div (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
      [else
      (error 'parse-sexpr "bad syntax in ~s" sexpr)]))
```

I can still compile the code, but if i will do `run (+ 5 3)` i will get 8 and if i try to `run (5 + 3)` i'm getting:

> Type Checker: Cannot apply expression of type Positive-Byte, since
>   it is not a function type in: (5 + 3)

why doe's this happend?

Comment: A tip for future questions, to debug a Type Checker error like this, you can usually abstract away most of your code with a function that has the same type, but does nothing. If you still get the same error then, you have ruled out a bunch of possible causes, and it will be much easier to see the actual problem.

Comment: Also, with `run` having the type `String -> Number`, did `(run (+ 5 3))` actually give you `8`? For me it gives a type checker error saying `Type Checker: type mismatch  expected: String  given: Positive-Index in: (+ 5 3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of what is an expression in typed racket, vs. what is an expression in your language. In your language, `(5 + 3)` is an expression, but in typed racket, it's a type error. So you need to represent `(5 + 3)` as **data** in typed racket.

One common way to do this, as @soegaard pointed out, is to put a `quote` in front of it, like this: `'(5 + 3)`. Though I hate writing it like that. What it *really* is, is `(list 5 '+ 3)`. So you can pass it to your new `parse-sexpr` function to get

```
> (parse-sexpr (list 5 '+ 3))
- : AE
(Add (Num 5) (Num 3))
```

Then you can pass that value to your `eval` function to get

```
> (eval (Add (Num 5) (Num 3)))
- : Number
8
```

Composed together:

```
> (eval (parse-sexpr (list 5 '+ 3)))
- : Number
8
```

But your `run` function takes a string, passes it to `string->sexpr` then passes that to `parse-sexpr` and then your `eval` function. So what you probably meant to do all along was this:

```
> (eval (parse-sexpr (string->sexpr "{5 + 3}")))
- : Number
8
> (run "{5 + 3}")
- : Number
8
```

Assuming that `string->sexpr` takes expressions with curly braces like that. What you were doing was `(run (5 + 3))`, which treats `(5 + 3)` as a typed racket expression. What you wanted was `(run "{5 + 3}")`, which treats `(5 + 3)` as an expression in your language, which is represented as data in typed racket.

Comment: ok i understand, so what i need to to is to create new racket-type and use it to make infix.

i create:
`(define-type Infix-sexpr
  [Num Number]
  [Infix-sexpr Symbole Infix-sexpr]
  )`

but when i click run i got:

define-type: cannot use the type name for a variant in: Infix-sexpr

what am i missing?

Comment: Well, no, you already have a type for that. It's called `AE`. The `AE` type doesn't care whether it's converted from infix syntax or anything else. It represents the meaning, not the syntax.

Comment: The `AE` used in the second step, after i get the sexpr tree.

From what i understand, i need to create racket-type, who will replace the sexpr, and will be able to cast infix string to list of infix expersion.

please correct me if i'm wrong, and if you and direction for the solution i will be more then happy

Comment: Is `(list 5 '+ 3)` not a valid `Sexpr`? I'm not familiar with `#lang pl`, only with `#lang typed/racket`.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it out in `#lang pl`, and, you already have a type for that, it's called `Sexpr`.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. It turns out `string->sexpr` takes expressions with curly braces, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by chance write

```
 (run (+ 5 3))
```

instead of

```
 (run '(+ 5 3))
```

?

If you write `(run (+ 5 3))` then Racket will compute `(+ 5 3)` first, and then call `(run 8)`. If you write `(run (5 + 3))` then Racket will attempt to evaluate `(5 + 3)` and that gives the error you see: the number `5` is not a function type, so it can not be used as in `(5 ...)`.

Comment: i wrote `run (+ 5 3)`.
but i change the parse-sexpr order value so it can fit to infix exper, but still it remains in the prefix, and i have no idea why?

Comment: Same thing. You need to write `(run '(+ 5 3))` in order for the run function to get a list with the elements '+, 5, and, 3.

Comment: ok, is it any way to make run get `(5 + 3)` like he accpet the `(+ 5 3)` without makeing it list?

Comment: @shukishtein I see in you code example that `run` expects a strings as input. You must therefore write: `(run "5+3")`.

Comment: Or perhaps `(run "(+ 5 3)")`   I couldn't see what `string->sexpr` does.